# How do I configure my server to forward "domain.com" to "www.domain.com"?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, rewrite, domain-name, url

I need to forward all visitors from "domain.com" to "www.domain.com".

I know this has something to do with altering the nginx config file but am not sure what to do or what code to use.

I am using nginx as the server.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/145141/nginx-forward-all-subdomains

Comment: Just do opposite: http://serverfault.com/questions/35955/how-to-get-nginx-to-redirect-from-www-to-non-www-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own NGINX setup, I made a separate vhost for domain.com:

```
server {
  listen   1.2.3.4:80;
  server_name  domain.com;
  rewrite  ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sgaduuw your solution have helped and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can't just have a link as an answer...

Anyway, check out this question: [Nginx: Forward all Subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/145141/nginx-forward-all-subdomains)

The config there should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the URL in the config file like this:

```
server {
    server_name  domain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    #My other config options
}
```

Comment: Thanks TiZon for your solution and it works and it helped me once again Thanks :)

Comment: @Jayesh Gopalan Could you mark the question as solved then? That wey it won't pop up on the main page as an unsolved question.